# Functional URL hit lambda twice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to make use of functional url in case of mono lambda function, I have created a functional url with no security.

URL was created successfully, but *Not able to hit that url using postman.* So I use chrome web browser to hit my url(Get request). But the problem was whenever I hit the url, My function gets executed twice.

If anyone have faced same issue, Please assist.

Comment: This can be possible if you are trying to convert your HTTP to HTTPS conversion, like re-direct to enforce SSL connection. Check your URL and try to hit only HTTPS. Because what happens is, when you hit- `http://example.org`, if it enforce the https, then again browser send another request to `https://example.org`, the second possibility that I can think off, chrome may be sending another request for `favicon.png`, you need to check possibilities here using `network` trouble shooting.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked, chrome is sending another request to get the favicon.
is there anyway we can disable this in chrome ?

Comment: Very pleased to know that mentioned solution worked for you, I don't think there is straight way to avoid that in the first request, but if you have other pages, you can see if this is helpful `https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/prevent-automatic-favicon-requests--cms-34762`, or you may have to do little research yourself. I'm adding my comment as solution, hopefully you will accept that as valid answer and it can help others, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities I can think off-

1. Chrome/browser sending another request for `favicon.png`
2. If you have configuration on server side that enforce HTTP to HTTPS conversion of the request, like re-direct to enforce SSL connection. In that case as well, browser send one request HTTP and redirect request to HTTPS. e.g when you hit- `http://example.org`, if it enforce the `https`, then again browser send another request to `https://example.org`.

You need to check possibilities here using network trouble shooting. Hope this will help you!

Comment: It's happening to me for favicon.png. Is there a way to limit or disable that?

Comment: @dataviews as far as I understand, its browser's default behavior, hence you can't control it. Even somehow if you stop it for your browser or set of users browser it won't serve the purpose. Because I'm sure if you are making any website or page, you must be expecting unknown people to use it as well, hence not a good idea to stop favicon request client side. `Solution can be on server side, just write a check to reject favicon requests.`

Comment: I'm using the lambda to do an oauth completion, so the URL is the redirect uri essentially (MVP stage on something). it works fine, but makes a secondary request from my browser. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that.